# How can i find all the images are loaded in ajax using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, image

Is it possible to find whether all the images are loaded in ajax content? I have used

```
var img = $('#slider img');
var length = img.length;

img.load(function(){
    length--;

    if(length === 0){
        alert("All images loaded");
    };
});
```

but the load is not working, it is not goning in to the loop...

Comment: I don't see a loop? Where is the above code called from? The element selection with `$('#slider img')` will only find elements that exist in the DOM at that moment, so you need to be sure it runs after your AJAX call has created the image elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn The loop which i have said is like am not getting the alert 'all images loaded'. The load function is getting binded to the imgs, but still it is not working

Comment: Are you saying your original code had a loop but for purposes of the question you've simplified it by putting an alert in instead? (If so, please edit your question so that it doesn't refer to things we can't see.) How do you know the load function is bound to the images, have you tried putting an alert or console.log in as the first line of the function to confirm how many times it gets called?

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn. Now it works. changed a bit of the code loop and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$('#slider img').each(function() {
      //Write pre loading script
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add event listener **load** before set up **src** attribute. Or you can scan images and check if every is loaded (by image size):

```
var img = $('#slider img');
var length = img.length;

img.each(function(){
    if ($(this).width() > 0 && $(this).height() > 0)
        length--;

    if(length === 0){
        alert("All images loaded");
    };
});
```

I not checked code.